# My blogger Javascript keeps making my pictures disappear

Tags: javascript, image, blogger

I recently added a javascript code that fits all images within the post width. It's so nice! but it's causing my images to disappear after a couple seconds, leaving the broken image icon. How can I fix this?
Here is the code I added to my page:

```
<script language='javascript'src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
/**
this script was written by Confluent Forms LLC http://www.confluentforms.com
for the BlogXpertise website http://www.blogxpertise.com
any updates to this script will be posted to BlogXpertise
please leave this message and give credit where credit is due!
**/
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the dimension of your content within the columns
    var areawidth = $('#Blog1').width();
    $('.post-body').find('img').each(function(n, image){
        var image = $(image);
        var height = image.attr('height');
        var width = image.attr('width');
        var newHeight = (height/width * areawidth).toFixed(0);
        image.attr('width',areawidth).attr('height',newHeight);
        var greater = Math.max(areawidth,newHeight);
        image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{3,4}/,'s' + greater)});
    });
});
//]]></script>
```

And here is the link to my site: benjaminkristenreeves.blogspot.com

Comment: I tried your blog site in IE and Chrome, but the images seem to remain. BTB, the CSS "expression" only is IE dependent - doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: A snippet of jQuery code doing basic stuff demanding credits, and the credits are almost longer than the code TT. Throw it away, do it in css. There is absolutely no need for javascript to accomplish that task and it's like 2 lines of css. Why is there a regular expression in code to resize an image?

Comment: it's most likely caused by the last line with the regex, it's changing the path to (source of) your image replacing "s" when followed by 3 or 4 digits with "s" plus the new size of the image for no obvious reason. If you remove that it'll work. this solution apparently requires to upload differently sized images for every possible image size.